# Upper Bound for $p(1-p) $ where $0 \le p \le 1$

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality, quadratics

In a book on statistics, I've seen the upper bound of $p(1-p) $ to be

$$ p(1-p) \le \frac{1}{4} $$

for $0 \le p \le 1$ which seemed correct. I tried to duplicate this with a simple derivation,

$$p(1-p) = C$$

$$p-p^2 = C$$

Taking derivatives of both sides, gives

$$1-2p=0$$

$$p=\frac{1}{2}$$

which is the value of $p$ at the maximum, and $1/2*1/2 = 1/4$. I obtained this without using the constraint $0 \le p \le 1$ though. How would I include this constraint? Through Lagrange? Is that overkill?

Comment: You need to check the values of $p-p^2$ at the bounds of your intervall. However, since your function defines a parabola, your maximum is global.

Comment: Right, the max is global no need to check for anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inequality: showing that $p(1-p)\leq \frac{1}{4}$ if $0&lt;p&lt;1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030249/inequality-showing-that-p1-p-leq-frac14-if-0p1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p(1-p)=p-p^2=-(p^2-p)=-((p-1/2)^2-(1/2)^2)=1/4-(p-1/2)^2 \le 1/4$ (for all values of $p$, but in probability theory only $0 \le p \le 1$ is relevant).

Answer (score 4):

If we do it the AM-GM way instead (valid since both $p, 1-p \ge 0$), we see that

$$\begin{align}\frac{p + (1 - p)}{2} &\ge \sqrt{p(1-p)}\\
\sqrt{p(1-p)} &\le \frac{1}{2}\\
p(1-p) &\le \frac{1}{4}\end{align}$$

with equality at $p = 1-p$ which simplifies into $p = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

$p(1-p)$ is a parabola with roots at $0$ and $1$. The midpoint of a parabola is where the vertex (maximum if it opens down, minimum if it opens up) occurs, which is at $p=\frac{1}{2}$. In this case, it opens down. You can also just note that if the unconstrained maximum lies within the constraints, then it must be the constrained maximum (that is, argmax(p(1-p)) = 1/2  ignoring the constraints, which lies within $[0,1]$, so it must indeed be the constrained maximum when you constrain to $[0,1]$).